# How to remove rusted screws?

Tags: screws, garage-door-opener, garage-door

I have these rusted screws in my garage door.

How do I remove them? I tried using pliers, a hammer, Water Displacement 40. Didn't come out.

[image]

Here is another view from the inside:

[image]

If someone has a tip regarding how to go about removing these two rusted screws, then please let me know.

Thanks kindly

Answer (score 2):

What you have on the inside looks like a rusty nut on a rusty threaded stud that is part of the broken rusty outside handle.

[image: blurry photo of rusty nut on rusty threaded stud/bolt]

You don't mention having tried a wrench (AKA spanner) - the closed end of a combination wrench offers the best grip. You may need to clean loose rust using a wire brush to get it to fit. An adjustable wrench might work better than the pliers you mentioned, Using a vise-grip (AKA locking pliers AKA mole-grip) on the outside may help if the outside parts rotate.

[image: combination-wrench, adjustable-wrench, locking-pliers]

You could cut them off with a hacksaw, a rotary tool (Dremel etc) or a multitool.

[image: hacksaw]
[image: rotary tool]
[image: multi-tool]

Sometimes you can use heat to help free up rusted/siezed parts like that. If you have a blowtorch, you could try this. Personally I'd cut them off since you probably don't want to reuse the nuts or the outer handle..

Answer (score 1):

These look like carriage bolts and not screws. Borrow a grinder and grind them off, then take a punch and drive them through.

Comment: I don't think it's that kind of problem.

Comment: Well then, I would need to know what kind of problem it is.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely those are [carriage bolts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_bolt) - a square section of the bolt shank engages to a square hole in what's left of the handle. However the carriage bolt's ability to resist turning is quite limited.  Once it cams out (rounds out the square hole), any hopes of unscrewing it non-destructively are dashed.  Pencil a line across handle and bolt so you can see when it's spun; if it turns more than 45 degrees it's a goner.

Grinding off the button-head outside will not help you. The square bolt shank will not pull through to the inside.

Don't be bashful about wrecking the inside handle, those are stock handles at a garage door supply house, I just mail-order them. Don't wreck the door (or more precise, its protective coating, why is it not rusting?)

I would start by sawing off any excess length of machine screw, the better to not have to remove rust from it.  Trying to run a nut up over crumbly rust is trying to fail.  Then hose the nut down with some proper penetrating oil like Kroil.

Then give it a shot with a wrench but use a socket wrench preferably 6-point so you don't round over the nut hexes.  The outer half-handle will want to turn, hold it so it doesn't gouge the door finish.  Once the carriage bolt head starts turning against the door handle remains, it has cammed out and you are done.

Now you're going to have to saw the nut off with a Dremel or better, a vibrating tool.

Comment: looks like there is room to just hack saw the screw behind the nut.

Comment: @Harper, why would grinding off the head of the carriage bolt be ineffective? I've manually created square holes for carriage bolts by drilling the proper sized hole and filed corners to take the bolt head. If I had cut away the "mushroom" head, the square would pull through easily. If the hole has been cammed out, that would allow for the square to pull through even more easily, no?

Comment: @fred_dot_u because the garage door is about 2" thick. Most likely this was not broached out square, most likely the square was stamped into the rusted out handle and driven (by means of tightening the bolt) the first 1/8" or whatever the carriage bolt required. Beyond that Id expect a round hole.  Can't put a square peg in a round hole.

Comment: That makes sense. I suppose even if the sheet metal on one side has a square hole, the opposite side would have a round one. I was thinking too two dimensionally.